# I want to add list of Bitmap images into grid view

Tags: java, android, gridview

Hello i want to get images from devices and display it in grid view when i change i to 3 it show me the image in position of 3 five times:

```
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(file[i]));

    private OpenDownloadedImages MyContext;
    ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmaps = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();

    public buttonAdapter(OpenDownloadedImages c){
        MyContext = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return file.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return file[i];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View vie = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_list_fav,null);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) vie.findViewById(R.id.imgFav);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(180,250));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        imageView.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
        try {
            File f=new File("sdcard/wallpaperHD");
            File file[] = f.listFiles();

            Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(file[i]));
            //ImageView img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.dImage);
            //img.setImageBitmap(b);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(b);

        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return imageView;
    }

    File f=new File("sdcard/wallpaperHD");
    File file[] = f.listFiles();
}
```

thank you !!

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot? I'm confused as to what you mean by "it show me the image in position of 3 five times"

Comment: As it should. Nice gimmick. Add a sixt one to have more fun! Is there any question?

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer here is the code : 
first i added new function :

public static Bitmap decodeFile(File f,int WIDTH,int HIGHT){

```
    try {
        //Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

        //The new size we want to scale to
        final int REQUIRED_WIDTH=WIDTH;
        final int REQUIRED_HIGHT=HIGHT;
        //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        int scale=1;
        while(o.outWidth/scale/2>=REQUIRED_WIDTH && o.outHeight/scale/2>=REQUIRED_HIGHT)
            scale*=2;

        //Decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize=scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
    return null;
}
```

and in get view change 
`Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(file[i]));`
with this code : `Bitmap bitmap = decodeFile(file[i],180,250);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);`